# Error 1053: my java wrapped application doesn't respond but it's actually running

Tags: java, windows-services

I'm writing an application in `Java`.

The aim is to take `infos` about computer software (`Ex: OS version, hotfix, disk capacity etc..`).

I needed to have some features that an exe provides (icon, company name) so i wrapped my `myapp.jar` to `myapp.exe`.

It works perfectly but when i try to add this application through `sc.exe create <myservice> binpath="mypath" .....` as service to windows and i try to run it, my application starts perfectly but the service manager says after 30 seconds that the service is not responding (`Error 1053`) and i really don't know how to make my app does it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Stefano

Comment: Take a look at [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/)